# how to make this query work in timescale?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have the following query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW aggregate
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT
json_build_object(
    'candles',
    (SELECT json_agg(array [EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_bucket), "open", high, low, "close", volume :: BIGINT]) AS json_array_of_arrays
    FROM exchange.candles_d1
    WHERE exchange.candles_d1.ticker = 'BTCUSDT' AND candles_d1.ts_bucket >= time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket) AND candles_d1.ts_bucket < time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket) + INTERVAL '1 hour'),

    'kvwap',
    (SELECT json_agg(array [EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_bucket), m1, m5, m15, m30, h1, h2, h4, d1, low, vwap, high]) AS json_array_of_arrays
    FROM exchange.kvwap_d1
    WHERE exchange.kvwap_d1.ticker = 'BTCUSDT' AND kvwap_d1.ts_bucket >= time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket) AND kvwap_d1.ts_bucket < time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket) + INTERVAL '1 hour'),

    'zones',
    (SELECT json_agg(array[EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_confirmation)::BIGINT, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_end)::BIGINT, confirmations, CAST(is_continuation AS INT)]) AS json_array_of_array
    FROM analysis.zones
    WHERE analysis.zones.ticker = 'BTCUSDT' AND "interval" = 'D1' AND ts_confirmation >= time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket) AND analysis.zones.ts_confirmation < time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket) + INTERVAL '1 hour')
)
FROM exchange.candles_d1;
```

but when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

> ERROR: invalid continuous aggregate query
> Detail: CTEs, subqueries and set-returning functions are not supported by continuous aggregates.

Am I to understand that the json_agg is not supported by continuous aggregates? any workaround?

Comment: create separate materialized views for the candle data, kvwap data, and zone data, and then join those views in the main VIEW aggregate ?

Comment: at some point I still need to call the json_agg function, and it seems to be the problem

Comment: you can use json_agg in each view, but don't put in json_build_object(), do it when joining the 3 in final MATERIALIZED VIEW aggregate...

Comment: and no need WITH (timescaledb.continuous) for the workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposed workaround, something like: (don't kill me if it doesn't work XD):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW candles_agg AS
SELECT
    time_bucket('1 hour', ts_bucket) AS hour_bucket,
    json_agg(array[EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_bucket), "open", high, low, "close", volume::BIGINT]) AS json_array_of_arrays
FROM
    exchange.candles_d1
WHERE
    ticker = 'BTCUSDT'
    AND ts_bucket >= time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket)
    AND ts_bucket < time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket) + INTERVAL '1 hour'
GROUP BY
    hour_bucket;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW kvwap_agg AS
SELECT
    time_bucket('1 hour', ts_bucket) AS hour_bucket,
    json_agg(array[EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_bucket), m1, m5, m15, m30, h1, h2, h4, d1, low, vwap, high]) AS json_array_of_arrays
FROM
    exchange.kvwap_d1
WHERE
    ticker = 'BTCUSDT'
    AND ts_bucket >= time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket)
    AND ts_bucket < time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket) + INTERVAL '1 hour'
GROUP BY
    hour_bucket;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW zones_agg AS
SELECT
    time_bucket('1 hour', ts_confirmation) AS hour_bucket,
    json_agg(array[EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_confirmation)::BIGINT, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_end)::BIGINT, confirmations, CAST(is_continuation AS INT)]) AS json_array_of_arrays
FROM
    analysis.zones
WHERE
    ticker = 'BTCUSDT'
    AND "interval" = 'D1'
    AND ts_confirmation >= time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket)
    AND ts_confirmation < time_bucket('1 hour', exchange.candles_d1.ts_bucket) + INTERVAL '1 hour'
GROUP BY
    hour_bucket;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW aggregate AS
SELECT
    json_build_object(
        'candles', c.json_array_of_arrays,
        'kvwap', k.json_array_of_arrays,
        'zones', z.json_array_of_arrays
    ) AS json_object
FROM
    candles_agg c
    JOIN kvwap_agg k ON k.hour_bucket = c.hour_bucket
    JOIN zones_agg z ON z.hour_bucket = c.hour_bucket;
```

Comment: I think this is the right approach, but testing is starting to show that my original queries don't work the way I expected with the aggregation :/ I was trying to collect all rows for a bucket, as array and then json the whole thing...
I'll mark your answer as goo because the method you proposed will work. I just need to find a solution for the aggregation itself :)